# Looking for a script to restore a SQL server backup

Tags: sql-server, powershell, backup-restoration

I'm looking for a script to restore a SQL Server 2005 backup. Ideally the script will have the following features

- handle backup files on a network location
- Handle different file structure of source and destination server ("With MOVE"?)
- Written in PowerShell

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm curious why you want to use PowerShell to run a SQL Command, when the Native T/SQL command will probably be easier to find and use?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to a [script](http://chadwickmiller.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!EA42395138308430!463.entry) I created

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [link text](http://www.databasejournal.com/img/usp_build_restore.sql). Ok, is not really a Powershell script. But it works on all Servers, 2000 or 2005 so far. And it does a great job for me. Just executing **master..usp_build_restore_script** and copy the relevant part for the Restore.

I did also an extension in Powershell. As a sample, before i execute a Restore, i like to see if the necessary files really exists or not. For this i just execute the **master..usp_build_restore_script** from Powershell and use test-path on all Backupfiles.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the different structures but [this post at sqlmusings.com](http://www.sqlmusings.com/2009/06/01/how-to-restore-sql-server-databases-using-smo-and-powershell) should be agood starting point for you.